# Combining AngularJS, HTML5 locations and superstatic

Tags: angularjs, node.js, http-redirect

I've been using the nodejs http-server to serve up my Angular app, but it doesn't work well with HTML5 locations, because using them requires the server to redirect, and http-server doesn't do that.  So I saw a recommendation to try  [superstatic](https://www.npmjs.com/package/superstatic), and installed it.  Then I set up the following superstatic.json file:

```
{
  "routes": {
    "Admin/**":"/index.html",
    "Give/**":"/index.html",
    "Pending/**":"/index.html",
    "Store/**":"/index.html"
  }
}
```

I launched it with

```
superstatic --config superstatic.json
```

While it correctly serves up my app if I start at "/", reloads load the index.html file, but do not do any of the angular processing of the file.

Has anyone successfully used superstatic with angular?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got mine perfectly working by setting my `superstatic.json` like this:

```
{
  "rewrites": [
    {"source":"/**","destination":"/index.html"}
  ]
}
```

Then run it with

```
superstatic --config superstatic.json
```

Comment: Finally found a solution for this issue! Thank you very much @Louie

Answer (score 1):

The following superstatic.json configuration works for me with AngularJS and HTML5 Mode.

```
{
    "routes": [
    {"**": "index.html"}
    ]
}
```

You don't need to specify every route combination in the config, unless you have specific route or state requirements.