# Angular URL removing # using express to route request

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I tried to remove '#' from angular-urls, I have done the tweaks in my front-end like

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

<base href="/*"> in my view file.
```

I am using express in by backend. THough Its works well but when I refresh page it gives me error url not found.

My default url is like from express to render view is like,

```
//server.js

app.use(express.static('app'));
var routes = require('./routes/index');
app.use('/', routes);


/routes/index
router.all('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('home');
});
```

It works in case if I click `http://localhost:1337/` first. It moves nicely to this `http://localhost:1337/first-param` but when I click `http://localhost:1337/first-param` directly without going to base url it gives me not found error.

Please don't give me hint for `.htaccess`. I don't want to use `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well.. you are only handling `'/'` route in your app. So every time you ask the server for another route say `'/something'`, the server does not know what to do.

Try This (Use router.get() instead of router.all() to only handle get requests):

```
router.get('/*', function(req, res) {
   res.render('home');
});
```

This should handle all the routes.

**UPDATE**

Of course you  might want to have other routes handled by your express app, say for your API.

To do that, I suggest you create your api in the format `'/api/foo/{bar}'`

And you set up your router in the following way :

```
router.route(/^((?!\/(api)).)*$/).get(function(req, res){res.render('home')});
```

The regular expression holds true for everything that does not start with `/api` and returns the home page.

Remember, add this configuration BELOW all the other routes to maintain the heirarchy.

**To summarize :** The last snippet of code handles all the routes except the ones that start with `/api` and you design your API to always start with `/api` . Use this method and it should work just fine.

Comment: I tried this as well but it always returns html in all services instead of data.

Comment: thats because you are handling "all" request formats. Try router.get() instead of router.all()

Comment: I did this also but rest of my get requests are getting html ;)

Comment: I just updated the answer. Let me know if it is not clear enough for you

Comment: Remember, the first snippet of code in the answer is not needed if you are applying the latter solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use [superstatic](https://www.npmjs.com/package/superstatic) to serve your application.

Then use the options in my answer here: [Combining AngularJS, HTML5 locations and superstatic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28506388/combining-angularjs-html5-locations-and-superstatic/34805890#34805890)

Comment: Please explain how. I edited question to show static.

Comment: Can't we achieve from express default request itself.

Comment: I tried using express for this before but got into trouble, got mine set up in like just 5 mins using superstatic

Comment: It wud be final if I fails to achieve from express only. Thank you