# How to turn off hashbangmode in AngularJs & Node.js?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

This question is put up by me after several efforts. but unfortunately no result. I'm using angularjs and expressjs. I turned off hashbang mode using `$location.html5Mode(true)` and adding `<base href="/">`. It worked for a glance.  But when I pressed F5 button. It showed me a very ugly page without any css or js script loaded ???? Any help would be appreciated. I'm currently using expressjs skeleton with node.js.

**Here's my App.Js File Code**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

var viewRoutes = require('./routes/view'),
    loginRoutes = require('./routes/login');

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));  //setting to HTML engine instead of EJS | JADE 
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


app.use('/', viewRoutes);
app.use('/login', loginRoutes);




// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

**Here's my COntroller File COde :**

```
var amApp = angular.module('amApp', ['ngRoute']);

amApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: '/home',
            controller: 'homeCtrl'
        })
        .when('/home', {
            templateUrl: '/home',
            controller: 'homeCtrl'
        })
        .when('/login', {
            templateUrl: '/login',
            controller: 'loginCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise('/');
}]);
```

**Here's my Route File named view.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index');
});


router.get('/home', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('pages/home');
});

router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('pages/login');
});

module.exports = router;
```

I'm using HTMl instead of EJS or JADE..

Comment: What's an example of a full url for your app including the hash?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the linking of your resources.

If you turn to html5 mode, the links for other resources like css have to be modified as well!

Open your developer tools (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/) and check for error messages. Are all paths correct?

Change the paths accordingly and try again :)

Comment: can you post some code snippet that help me out practically!

Comment: Can you post your error messages? The developer tools should show you an error why your css is not shown :)

Comment: lisa i'm not getting error any... and i've posted my code .. if it helps you..hope

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add something like these lines of code into your `viewRoutes` and `loginRoutes` files (this needs to be server-side) and you should be good. These will add the hash in the url whenever someone tries to request a url beginning with `/home` or `/login`. Let me know if you have any issues with it.

```js
app.get('/home/*', function(req, res) {
  res.redirect('/#' + req.originalUrl);
});

app.get('/login/*', function(req, res) {
  res.redirect('/#' + req.originalUrl);
});
```

Let's say your page is at `mypage.com/#/index` in a normal situation. The server will handle the request to `mypage.com/` and your Angular code will handle the `#/index` route. When you turn off hashbang, you now have this: `mypage.com/index`. When you refresh the page, your browser will attempt to go to `mypage.com/index`, which would normally be handled by your server as the `/index` route since there's no hash. I assume you haven't written a handler for that route yet (in your server) and that's why the strange page is shown. That page could even be a static file that's being accessed by accident, depending on naming and server configuration.

I had the same issue on a site I was making and had to handle the route via express to reroute `mypage.com/index` to `mypage.com/#/index`. That would send the user to the correct location for your angular routing, then the browser would hide the hashbang. This code on my express server worked well for my page:

```js
app.get('/chat-room/*', function(req, res) {
 res.redirect('/#' + req.originalUrl);
});

app.get('/admin/*', function(req, res) {
 res.redirect('/#' + req.originalUrl);
});
```

This redirects any requests to `mydomain.com/chat-room/` or `mydomain.com/admin/` to the correct, angular-routing appropriate `mydomain.com/#/chat-room/` or `mydomain.com/#/admin/` respectively.

Comment: can you post some code snippet that help me out practically!

Comment: @AmulyaKashyap Sure, I'll post what I have, but that's specific to my server.

Comment: wait.. let me post that would help you to give more accurate and feasible solution as well

Comment: @AmulyaKashyap Sounds good. I've posted my stuff, but will update once you post yours.

Comment: @AmulyaKashyap Looks like your routes are set up here: `var viewRoutes = require('./routes/view'), loginRoutes = require('./routes/login');`It may be better to look through those files and add code like that in them in the appropriate places.

Comment: @AmulyaKashyap Yes, the files are added, but the code needs to be added to those files as appropriate. If you are not familiar with how to do that, then posting those files as well will give a better idea as to how exactly the code needs to be inserted.

Comment: all the files have been posted what else should I ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be handling all the routes in your express app, not just the default "/" route. The express app is not being able to determine the updated route when you are refreshing the page in a state other than "/".

Look at my answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35216601/angular-url-removing-using-express-to-route-request/35216738#35216738) question.